# Javascript mouseover mouseout menu

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I'm trying to make this javascript menu work where, when I hover over AAA its submenu shows and on BBB its submenu shows.

It is implemented as a javascript which toggles the #subnav1 and #subnav2 css visibility where the two overlap one another.

However it seems only BBB mouseover works correctly, I suspect because the subnav2 is on top of the subnav1 however even messing with z-index doesn't solve the quirk..
Any idea?

[image]

Below is the code.. I left the css style so to make it look like a menu, hope it's not too long for an sscce

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    #nav {
    float:left;
    height:20px;
    width:50%;
    font-size:.8em;
    margin:10px 0 0 20%;
    }

    #nav li,#subnav1 li,#subnav2 li {
    display:inline;
    }

    #nav ul li a,#subnav1 ul li a,#subnav2 ul li a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
    }

    #nav ul,#subnav1 ul,#subnav2 ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

    #subnav1,#subnav2 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    }

    #subnavs {
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #ccc;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:20px;
    width:60%;
    font-size:.8em;
    margin:0 0 0 20%;
    padding:3px 0 0 10px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li onmouseover="showAAA(true, 'subnav1')" onmouseout="showAAA(false, 'subnav1')"><a>AAA</a></li>
<li onmouseover="showAAA(true, 'subnav2')" onmouseout="showAAA(false, 'subnav2')"><a>BBBB</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="subnavs">
<div id="subnav1" onmouseover="showAAA(true, 'subnav1')" onmouseout="showAAA(false, 'subnav1')">
<ul style="display: none; z-index: 10;">
<li><a>AAAAAAAA1</a></li>
<li><a>AAAAAAAA2</a></li>
<li><a>AAAAAAAA3</a></li>
<li><a>AAAAAAAA4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="subnav2" onmouseover="showAAA(true, 'subnav2')" onmouseout="showAAA(false, 'subnav2')">
<ul style="display: none; z-index: -10;">
<li><a>BBBBBBBB1</a></li>
<li><a>BBBBBBBB2</a></li>
<li><a>BBBBBBBB3</a></li>
<li><a>BBBBBBBB4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function showAAA(show, subnavid) 
            {
            var subNav1 = document.getElementById(subnavid);
            var ull = subNav1.getElementsByTagName("ul");
            for (var i = 0, ii = ull.length; i < ii; i++) 
            {
                if(show) 
                {
                  ull[i].style.display = "block";
                  ull[i].style.zIndex = 10;
                }
                else 
                {
                  ull[i].style.display = "none";
                  ull[i].style.zIndex = -10;
                }
            }
            };
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: No need for JavaScript. You can do this with pure css which is obviously better, quicker to load etc. http://csswizardry.com/demos/css-dropdown/

Comment: Seems to work fine in chrome on my mac, what os and browser are you testing on? Please also note functionality should NEVER be JavaScript dependent. You can easily do this with css.

Comment: on firefox when I hover over AAA it shows AAAAA1 but as soon as I move my mouse over AAAA1, BBBB1 shows..

Comment: the pure css menu you suggest is a dropdown menu, however I need a separate submenu as in the example above... :(